# Unable to set appropriate rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to block access via rewrite to IBM WebSphere WCM:

```
/wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login.jsp
```

And allow access to everything else under

```
/wps/*
```

Any ideas? I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login\.jsp [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wps.*
RewriteRule ^/.* https://myhost.com/wps/portal [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wanted a "rewrite"?

Comment: Where are these directives being used?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead (you don't need to use mod_rewrite here):

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login.jsp'">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

This serves a 403 Forbidden for the specific URL as stated.

(Requires Apache 2.4)

---

Using mod_rewrite:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login\.jsp [OR,NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wps.*
> RewriteRule ^/.* https://myhost.com/wps/portal [L,R=permanent]
> ```

In a `.htaccess` context, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash, so the *pattern* `^/.*` will never match (so the request is never "blocked"). However, you need the slash prefix if the rule is being used directly in a server or virtualhost context.

Since you only want to block a specific URL, you don't need to check that it's *not* something else (ie. does not start with `/wps`). But OR'ing these two conditions does not make sense (according to your criteria) as it would block the stated URL *and* every other URL that does not start with `/wps`.

This also issues a 301 redirect, it doesn't specifically "block" the request.

To block just that one URL you would need something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login\.jsp - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following (here's a snip of my rewrites)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wps/portal [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wps/wcm/webinterface.*
RewriteRule ^/,* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wps/portal [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*(jsp|jsv|wml|chtml) [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(htm|html|js|pdf|swf|ico|gif|jpg|css|png) [NC]
...
RewriteRule ^/,* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wps/portal [L,R=permanent]
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `^/,*` - That looks like a comma-star in the regex, not a dot-star as it should be (like in the first rule). It still "works". But just `^` only would suffice here. However, you should match what you can in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, not use a separate `RewriteCond` (condition) directive. Note that in the last rule, the regex in the _conditions_ are too vague and matching those strings anywhere in the URL-path (too much), not just the file extension (which is presumably the intention).

Comment: heh, its not a comma in the config - I typoed =)